# .readlines() shouldn't return an array?

Tags: python, readlines

I have a problem with `.readlines()`.
it used to only return the line specified, i.e. if I ran

```
f1 = open('C:\file.txt','r')
filedata = f1.readlines(2)
f1.close()
print filedata
```

it should print the second line of **file.txt.**
However now when I run that same code, it returns the entire contents of the file in an array, with each line in the file as a separate object in the array. I am using the same PC and am running the same version of `python (2.7).`

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: The argument to `readlines` is a hint about what size buffer to use, which is probably ignored by the built-in `file` type. It is not a request for a  specific line.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `readlines`; it reads the entire file into memory, *then* selects the desired line. Instead, just read the first `n` lines, then break.

```
n = 2
with open('C:\file.txt','r') as f1:
    for i, filedata in enumerate(f1, 1):
        if i == n:
            break
print filedata.strip()
```

The [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) also provides a recipe for consuming the first *n* items of an sequence:

```
def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

You might use it like this:

```
n = 2
with open('C:\file.txt','r') as f1:
    consume(f1, n-1)
    filedata = next(f1)
print filedata.strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
f1.readlines(2)
```

To this:

```
f1.readlines()[2]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\8865460-fp01\EU_HomeFolders\ITExam57\Troubleshooter CAU\Task2\Task2.py", line 7, in <module>
    filedata = f1.readlines[1]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: ah, Patricks solution fixed it. Thanks very much for your help guys.